# Where does the business logic go in a React-native app?

Tags: android, react-native

Inside the React-Native documentation, I only see examples using props, states, styles, and rendering. Everything in App.js

Where is business logic supposed to go?

In particular, I would like to fetch URLs with GET/POST, and manipulate the data, before going in

```
render() {

return (
  <View style={{ flexGrow: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' 
}}>
    ...
  </View>
);
}
```

to render something on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react native; the render function is simply for rendering. You can have all the other logic within other functions which changes a value within the screen's state. This will refresh the screen and re-render with the new values.

For simple example:

```
export default class MyScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {myValue: 0};
  }

  getMyValue=()=>{ 
    this.setState({myValue: 10});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.getMyValue}>
          <Text>Get My Value</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>My Value is: {this.state.myValue}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

In this example; the "myValue" will be first shown as 0 and once the button is press will turn to 10 instead. If you want to get the data automatically after the screen is loaded; you can set the code in **componentDidMount** function.